# How to use preprocessing_function in Keras 2.1.5

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use Transfer learning on VGG16 pretrained model for image classification task with 13 classes by retraining last 4 layers of the pretrained netowrk.

I am also using ImageDataGenerator from keras as mentioned [here](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/).

In this method, I am not able to figure out how should i use vgg16's `preprocess_input` method imported from `from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input` in ImageDataGenerator.

Whenever i run the code i get an error saying **JpegImageFile’ object is not subscriptable**

```
from keras.applications import VGG16
from keras import layers
from keras import optimizers
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_dir = ''
validation_dir = ''
vgg_conv = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))


for layer in vgg_conv.layers[:-4]:
    layer.trainable = False

for layer in vgg_conv.layers:
    print(layer, layer.trainable)

model = Sequential()

# Add the vgg convolutional base model
model.add(vgg_conv)

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(13, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest',
    preprocessing_function = preprocess_input
    )

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_batchsize = 100
val_batchsize = 20

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=train_batchsize,
    class_mode='categorical'
    )

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_dir,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=val_batchsize,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=False)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
              metrics=['acc'])
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=550,
    epochs=30,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=430)

model.save('small_last4.h5')
```

As suggested at various places, I also tried custom preprocess func. This also doesn't work.

```
vgg_mean = np.array([123.68, 116.779, 103.939], dtype=np.float32).reshape((3,1,1))
    def vgg_preprocess(x):
        """
            Subtracts the mean RGB value, and transposes RGB to BGR.
            The mean RGB was computed on the image set used to train the VGG model.
            Args:
                x: Image array (height x width x channels)
            Returns:
                Image array (height x width x transposed_channels)
        """
        x = x - vgg_mean
        return x[:, ::-1] # reverse axis rgb->bgr
```

Interestingly this problem is only in Keras 2.1.5. In 2.1.4 it works fine. The drawback that I am facing in downgrading keras is that my training time has drastically increased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a labda layer before adding vgg_conv like this:

```
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input
model = Sequential()
model.add(Lambda(preprocess_input, name='preprocessing', input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
model.add(vgg_conv)
...
```

unfortunately using `preprocess_input` from `keras.applications.vgg16` doesn't seem to work for me but you could try importing from `inception_v3`. Hopefully we are talking about the same preprocessing but i am not entirely sure.

Comment: I am talking about model specific preprocessing where in VGG16 it subtracts mean RGB value from al images and uses images in BGR order. Am i correct to use `preprocess_input `  in Lambda layer ?

Comment: i think you are correct. You can try this out and check the results

Comment: Cool, I will try out